# $u_t = u_{xx}$ and $u(x,0)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,t)$ be a bounded solution of

$u_t = u_{xx}$

$u(x,0)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u(1,t)=?$

My attempt:

I wrote $u=T X$

I want to use separation of variables.

$T= Ce^{\lambda t}$

I can solve by formula if i know how $u(x,t)$ bhehaves if $x=0$

But i think this approach will not wok. is there any other shorter way to it?

Comment: Have you tried Laplace Transform?

Comment: yes. very lengthy from laplsace

Answer (score 1):

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_{-{\infty}}^\infty e^{\frac{(x-y)^2}{4 \pi t}} u(y,0) dy$

$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_{-{\infty}}^\infty e^{\frac{(x-y)^2}{4 \pi t}} \frac{e^{2y}-1}{e^{2y}+1} dy$

use transformation $z =\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{4t}}$

$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi }} \int_{-{\infty}}^\infty e^{-z^2} \frac{e^{2(1+z\sqrt{4t})}-1}{e^{2(1+z\sqrt{4t})}+1} dt$

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(1,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi }} \int_{-{\infty}}^\infty e^{-z^2} (\frac{1}{1})= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi }} \sqrt{\pi} (1)=1$